# CanCan Permissions - Do they have to be explicit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cancan

I'm new to RoR and am utilizing CanCan for authorization. I'm wondering if I have to be explicit with every single ability that a user may have.

I'm probably not being clear enough, so I'll post some code to help illustrate my question.

```
if user.is_admin?
   can :manage, all
end

if user.is_director?
   can :update, Camp
end
```

In this case, would the director only be able to update a camp? Or would I have to denote what he/she specifically cannot do as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the moment you implement CanCan you have to explicit, as long as you call the `authorize_resource` (or `load_and_authorize_resource`) in the matching controller.

So yes (, if you call one of authorize methods in the `CampController`).

*(Also the director role should not overlap with the admin role ;) If it does it just get all permissions. And isn't it `:all`?)*

Comment: Yeah it is :all. I'm still getting used to the syntax ;) Thanks for your help though, I sorted everything out by controlling access in both the controller and view layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you added `check_authorization` to your `ApplicationController`, then yes, it will default to be locked down for all controller actions, unless specifically overwritten by `skip_authorization_check`.

See this [GitHub](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/191) discussion around this issue.